# Shrew Configuration to Allow all traffic over the VPN connection

Tags: vpn, ip-address, shrew

I want to route all the traffic through my VPN connection, i have already tried with the Policies section without success, https://www.whatismyip.com/ is still detecting my ip as i were not connected to the VPN, is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance